# Identifier construction in nim macros (instead of templates)

Tags: macros, nim-lang

In nim, if I am writing a macro, how do I explicitly construct a name from an argument. Specifically in the nim manual (see [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates-identifier-construction)) we have the following example of "identifier construction"

```
template typedef(name: untyped, typ: typedesc) =
  type
    `T name`* {.inject.} = typ
    `P name`* {.inject.} = ref `T name`

typedef(myint, int)
var x: PMyInt
```

How can I accomplish the same thing if I want typedef to be a macro instead of a template?

Answer (score 1):

any template can trivially become a macro. here:

```
template typedef(name: untyped, typ: typedesc) =
  type
    `T name`* {.inject.} = typ
    `P name`* {.inject.} = ref `T name`

typedef(myint, int)
var x: PMyInt

import macros
import std/genasts
macro typedef2(name:untyped, typ:typedesc) =
  result = genast(name,typ):
    type
      `T name`* {.inject.} = typ
      `P name`* {.inject.} = ref `T name`

typedef2(yourint, int)
var y: PYourInt

x = new int
x[] = 3
y = x
assert (y[] == 3)
```

but that's not helpful.

if you find yourself needing to step up from template to macro-land, it's because you need to manipulate the ast directly. so the first thing you do is figure out what the ast of your desired output is:

```
import macros
dumpTree: # dumpAstGen is also helpful
  type
    TMytype* = int
    PMytype* = ref TMytype
```

```
  TypeSection
    TypeDef
      Postfix
        Ident "*"
        Ident "Tmyname"
      Empty
      Ident "int"
    TypeDef
      Postfix
        Ident "*"
        Ident "Pmyname"
      Empty
      RefTy
        Ident "Tmyname"
```

`dumpAstGen` will output the exact code you'd need to put into your macro but it's less clear visually, so i'm using `dumpTree`.

now we make a macro that constructs that exact ast:

```
macro typedef3(name: untyped, typ: typedesc) =
  result = nnkTypeSection.newNimNode()
  result.add nnkTypeDef.newTree(
    nnkPostfix.newTree(
      ident"*",
      ident "T" & name.strVal),
    newEmptyNode(),
    typ)

  result.add nnkTypeDef.newTree(
    nnkPostfix.newTree(
      ident"*",
      ident "P" & name.strVal),
    newEmptyNode(),
    nnkRefTy.newTree(typ))

  #echo result.treerepr

typedef3(yourtype, float)
```

at the end we echo the ast we just made so we can compare it against what we were expecting

here it is as `echo result.repr` just for clarity:

```
type
  Tyourtype* = float
  Pyourtype* = ref float
```